# Parsing text to multiple columns

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, parsing

I have a feed that is populating a single text field in a table with statistics.
I need to pull this data into multiple fields in another table 
but the strange format makes importing automatically difficult.

The file format is flat text but an example is below:

```
08:34:52 Checksum=180957248,TicketType=6,InitialUserType=G,InitialUserID=520,CommunicationType=Incoming,Date=26-03-2012,Time=08:35:00,Service=ST,Duration=00:00:14,Cost=0.12
```

Effectively it's made up of:

```
[timestamp] [Field1 name]=[Field1 value],[Field2 name]=[Field2 value],[Field4 name]=[Field4 value]...[CR]
```

All fields are always in the same order but **not always present**.
Total columns could be anywhere from 5 to 30.

I've tried the below function to translate it which seems to work mostly but seems to randomly skip fields:

Parsing the data:

```
(SELECT [Data].[dbo].[GetFromTextString] ( 'Checksum=' ,',' ,RAWTEXT)) AS RowCheckSum,
(SELECT [Data].[dbo].[GetFromTextString] ( 'TicketType=' ,',' ,RAWTEXT)) AS TicketType,
```

And the Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFromTextString]
-- Input start and end and return value.
   (@uniqueprefix VARCHAR(100),
    @commonsuffix VARCHAR(100),
    @datastring VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) -- Picked Value.
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ADJLEN INT = LEN(@uniqueprefix)

    SET @datastring = @datastring + @commonsuffix

   RETURN ( 
    CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(@uniqueprefix,@datastring) > 0) 
         AND (CHARINDEX(@uniqueprefix + @commonsuffix,@datastring) = 0)
    THEN SUBSTRING(@datastring, PATINDEX('%' + @uniqueprefix + '%',@datastring)+@ADJLEN, CHARINDEX(@commonsuffix,@datastring,PATINDEX('%' + @uniqueprefix + '%',@datastring))- PATINDEX('%' + @uniqueprefix + '%',@datastring)-@ADJLEN) ELSE NULL END
)
END
```

Could anyone suggest a better/cleaner way to strip out the data or could someone work out why this formula skips rows?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Does this have to be done in SQL? It would be much cleaner to do this in another layer that supports Arrays and Key-Value Pairs.

Comment: What brand of SQL are you using?

Comment: The only tools I have available are SQL Server 2008 and Crystal Reports 2008, I could possibly access the data through a VB.net app but this would have to be run on a client machine, I'd prefer to have the process automated to run nightly (when there is no load on the server) as potential rows will be 5000+ per night.

Comment: Running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: What format are you trying to import to?

Comment: Target is a table in the server, with columns matching the possible item in the file (at the moment all columns are varchars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE - THE FIRST SOLUTION IS RUBBISH. I HAVE LEFT IN IT FOR HISTORICAL REASONS, BUT A BETTER SOLUTION IS CONTAINED BELOW**

I am not even sure if this will be faster than your current method, but it is the way I would approach the issue (If i was forced into an SQL only solution). The first thing that is required is a table valued function that will perform a split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@TextToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Values TABLE (Position INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, TextValues VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TextToSplit) > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT @Values 
            SELECT  LEFT(@TextToSplit, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TextToSplit) - 1)
            SET @TextToSplit = SUBSTRING(@TextToSplit, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TextToSplit) + 1, LEN(@TextToSplit))

        END
        INSERT @Values VALUES (@TextToSplit) 
    RETURN
END
```

For my example I am working from a temp table @Worklist, you may need to adapt yours accordingly, or you could just insert the relevant data into @Worklist where I have used dummy data:

```
DECLARE @WorkList TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, TextField VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @WorkList
SELECT  '08:34:52 Checksum=180957248,TicketType=6,InitialUserType=G,InitialUserID=520,CommunicationType=Incoming,Date=26-03-2012,Time=08:35:00,Service=ST,Duration=00:00:14,Cost=0.12'
UNION
SELECT  '08:34:52 Checksum=180957249,TicketType=5,InitialUserType=H,InitialUserID=521,CommunicationType=Outgoing,Date=27-03-2012,Time=14:27:00,Service=ST,Duration=00:15:12,Cost=0.37'
```

The main bit of the query is done here. It is quite long, so I have tried to comment it as well as possible. If further clarification is required I can add more comments.

```
DECLARE @Output TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, TextField VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @KeyPairs TABLE (WorkListID INT NOT NULL, KeyField VARCHAR(MAX), ValueField VARCHAR(MAX))

-- STORE TIMESTAMP DATA - THIS ASSUMES THE FIRST SPACE IS THE END OF THE TIMESTAMP
INSERT @KeyPairs 
SELECT  ID, 'TimeStamp', LEFT(TextField, CHARINDEX(' ', TextField))
FROM    @WorkList

-- CLEAR THE TIMESTAMP FROM THE WORKLIST
UPDATE  @WorkList
SET     TextField = SUBSTRING(TextField, CHARINDEX(' ', TextField) + 1, LEN(TextField))

DECLARE @ID INT = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @WorkList)
WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        -- SPLIT THE STRING FIRST INTO ALL THE PAIRS (e.g. Checksum=180957248)
        INSERT @Output
        SELECT  TextValues
        FROM    dbo.Split((SELECT TextField FROM @WorkList WHERE ID = @ID), ',')

        DECLARE @ID2 INT = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @Output)

        -- FOR ALL THE PAIRS SPLIT THEM INTO A KEY AND A VALUE (USING THE POSITION OF THE SPLIT FUNCTION)
        WHILE @ID2 IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT @KeyPairs
                SELECT  @ID, 
                        MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 1 THEN TextValues ELSE '' END),
                        MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 2 THEN TextValues ELSE '' END)
                FROM    dbo.Split((SELECT TextField FROM @Output WHERE ID = @ID2), '=')

                DELETE  @Output
                WHERE   ID = @ID2

                SET @ID2 = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @Output)
            END

        DELETE  @WorkList
        WHERE   ID = @ID

        SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @WorkList)
    END

-- WE NOW HAVE A TABLE CONTAINING EAV MODEL STYLE DATA. THIS NEEDS TO BE PIVOTED INTO THE CORRECT FORMAT
-- ENSURE COLUMNS ARE LISTED IN THE ORDER YOU WANT THEM TO APPEAR
SELECT  *
FROM    @KeyPairs p
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(ValueField)
            FOR KeyField IN 
                (   [TimeStamp], [Checksum], [TicketType], [InitialUserType], 
                    [InitialUserID], [CommunicationType], [Date], [Time],
                    [Service], [Duration], [Cost]
                )
        ) AS PivotTable;
```

---

**EDIT (4 YEARS LATER)**

A recent upvote brought this to my attention and the I hate myself a little bit for ever posting this answer in its current form.

A much better split function would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
(   WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1), (1)) n (N)),
    N2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 a CROSS JOIN N1 b),
    N3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 a CROSS JOIN N2 b),
    N4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N3 a CROSS JOIN N3 b),
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (   SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
        SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM n4
    ),
    cteStart(N1) AS 
    (   SELECT t.N+1 
        FROM cteTally t
        WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0)
    )
    SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)), 
            Position = s.N1,
            ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1)
    FROM cteStart s
);
```

Then there is no need for looping at all, you just have a proper set based solution by calling the split function twice to get your EAV style data set:

```
DECLARE @WorkList TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, TextField VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @WorkList
SELECT  '08:34:52 Checksum=180957248,TicketType=6,InitialUserType=G,InitialUserID=520,CommunicationType=Incoming,Date=26-03-2012,Time=08:35:00,Service=ST,Duration=00:00:14,Cost=0.12'
UNION
SELECT  '08:34:52 Checksum=180957249,TicketType=5,InitialUserType=H,InitialUserID=521,CommunicationType=Outgoing,Date=27-03-2012,Time=14:27:00,Service=ST,Duration=00:15:12,Cost=0.37';

WITH KeyPairs AS
(   SELECT  w.ID, 
            [Timestamp] = LEFT(w.TextField, CHARINDEX(' ', w.TextField)),
            KeyField = MAX(CASE WHEN v.ItemNumber = 1 THEN v.Item END),
            ValueField = MAX(CASE WHEN v.ItemNumber = 2 THEN v.Item END)
    FROM    @WorkList AS w
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(SUBSTRING(TextField, CHARINDEX(' ', TextField) + 1, LEN(TextField)), ',') AS kp
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(kp.Item, '=') AS v
    GROUP BY w.ID, kp.ItemNumber,w.TextField
)
SELECT  *
FROM   KeyPairs AS kp
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(ValueField)
            FOR KeyField IN 
                (   [Checksum], [TicketType], [InitialUserType], 
                    [InitialUserID], [CommunicationType], [Date], [Time],
                    [Service], [Duration], [Cost]
                )
        ) AS pvt;
```

Comment: That looks like an excellent solution, tested on some of the data and it does run quickly using select. If I wanted to use this to insert, how would it handle null/missing values or if a key is not present in all lines? I need to set-up my permanent table to include all 30 fields but have them null-able.

Comment: It would just return `NULL` if there is no value for a certain key.

Comment: But if I am doing `INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM @Keypairs...` will it insert the correct values into the correct columns or will it insert null values for missing columns?

Comment: You have to list the columns in order within the `FOR` statement in the PIVOT, whatever values you list there will appear in the select statement. As an example try adding `[Example], [For], [Missing], [Keys]` after `[Service], [Duration], [Cost]` in the final select statement. As long as the columns you list for the pivot match those you want to insert to (plus whatever you are grouping by, in my example this was worklist ID). If you set up an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.SQLFiddle.com) with some sample data and tables I can create a more tailored example for you if you like.

Comment: I understand now, I've not used PIVOTS before so I was a bit unsure how they worked, I've tested the function with some live data and it's working fantastically, thank you for your time!